# Return Type of Java Generic Methods

Tags: java, generics, methods, return-value, enumeration

I wonder why generic methods which return nothing `void` are (or can be) declared this way:

```java
   public static <E> void printArray( E[] inputArray ) {
     // Display array elements              
     for ( E element : inputArray ){        
        System.out.printf( "%s ", element );
     }
     System.out.println();
   }
```

It seems like `<E>` is the type of the returned object, but the method returns nothing in fact. So what is the real meaning of `<E>` in this case specifically and in generic methods generally?

Comment: Worth noting that `<E>` is not needed here. The method could just as well accept an Object array.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

This question suits one of my old notes. I hope this illustration helps:

[image]
[image]

Comment: great answer + 1, might be worth mentioning that in your first method you can use Void (uppercase 'V') for the return type T... though 'y' would have to have a null value

Comment: Addend to answer, if the type can be inferred from class type, it's not required in method.

Comment: I am not going to downvote, but this is rubish answer in terms of format - not searchable, copyable etc..

Answer (score 11):

The `<E>` is the generic type parameter declaration. It means "this method has a single type parameter, called `E`, which can be any type".

It's not the return type - that comes *after* the type parameter declaration, just before the method name. So the return type of the `printArray` method in your question is still `void`.

See [section 8.4 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4) for more details about method declarations.

Answer (score 6):

It's not the type of the returned object. It indicates that `E`, in the method signature, is a generic type and not a concrete type. Without it, the compiler would look for a class named `E` for the argument of the method.

Answer (score 4):

The < E > is called a formal type parameter. It is not the return type of the method. It basically says that the method can accept as parameters arrays of different types (E[] inputArray).

Answer (score 3):

**E** is used as a placeholder for the actual type that will be passed to Gen function when this function will call.

suppose **E** can be replaced by **integer**