# How generics in java works for the following program?

Tags: java, generics, overloading

```
public class Program {

    private static <Program> void foo(Program x){
        System.out.println(x+"-->1");
    }

    private static void foo(final int i){
        System.out.println(i+"-->2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = 10;
        foo(i);
    }

}
```

And the output is:

```
10-->1
```

I wasn't able to find any relevant discussion on this topic. However, the answer to a different topic confused me a little:-
[Return Type of Java Generic Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377248/return-type-of-java-generic-methods)

According to them the generic `<Program>` has nothing to do with return type but in my case if I change a little to this program as below then the output is different.

```
public class Program {

    private static <Integer> void foo(Program x){
        System.out.println(x+"-->1");
    }

    private static void foo(final int i){
        System.out.println(i+"-->2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = 10;
        foo(i);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
10-->2
```

I am using JDK1.7

Comment: In your second example, only the second version of `foo()` has a signature which can match to what you are calling in `main()`.  In the first example, there must be a precedence rule which matches the `Integer` call to the generic function before unboxing and calling the alternative is considered.

Comment: You are defining a new generic type parameter `Program` on this line: `private static <Program> void foo(Program x) {`. That type parameter has nothing to do with your class named `Program`. When you change the name of the type parameter to `Integer`, the parameter `Program x` suddenly has a type of your actual class `Program`. Lesson: Don't name your type parameters to actual classes that exist.

Comment: Your code would be tons easier to follow if your generics parameter names followed the convention of being spelled with a single uppercase letter. Regardless, it's hopelessly confusing when you name them the same as a concrete type, much less one that's in scope. Segregate your generics parameter names from your type names!

Comment: It's a interview question asked recently....Any way your ans make sense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your first example, You're not actually specifying argument of type `Program`, it is a generic. That type parameter has nothing to do with your class named `Program`. You will get same result by making a typo like this:

```
public class Program {

    private static <Programmmm> void foo(Programmmm x){
        System.out.println(x+"-->1");
    }

    private static void foo(final int i){
        System.out.println(i+"-->2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = 10;
        foo(i);
    }

}
```

However, in your second example, the parameter is literally of type `Program` and so it doesn't match when called as `foo(10);` and you get result from second method.

Answer (score 13):

In the first case, `Program` is the name of the generic parameter used for the method. It can be any name. The important thing is that the method argument is an Object, so when you call your method with an Integer argument, it uses the version that takes Object.

In the second case the generic parameter is named `Integer` (don't do this) but the argument the method takes is a Program. So by calling it with an Integer, there is not valid `Object` or integer version so it unboxes the value.

In terms of [method overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9), which describes the order that overloading is resolved. That will tell you why the first version usings the `Object` method instead of the `int` method.

The second issue is that you have named your generic parameters concrete types, which is confusing. It is easier to see if you don't do that.

```
private static <T> void foo(T x){
    System.out.println(x+"-->1");
}
```

Now it is clearer, `T` is a parameterized argument. In your second version,

```
private static <T> void foo(Program x){
    System.out.println(x+"-->1");
}
```

Now it is clear, your argument *has* to be a Program object, and not just any object.

Comment: Bonus points if you find a like to the relevant portion of the JLS discussing this ^ ^

Comment: Don't call the type parameter `Program` either, because it is the name of his main class. When he renames the type parameter to `Integer`, the parameter type suddenly changes to the actual class `Program`.