# diamond operator with generic type as returned parameter

Tags: java, diamond-operator

In Java I've found strange method declaration like that:

```
<T> T org.apache.commons.dbutils.BeanProcessor.toBean(ResultSet rs, Class<T> type) throws SQLException
```

What means this `<T> T`? What means this `<T>` before `T` and why the returned type is not just `"T"`?

I have download the source code of `org.apache.commons.dbutils.BeanProcessor` class and found the following method:

```
private <T> T createBean(ResultSet rs, Class<T> type,
        PropertyDescriptor[] props, int[] columnToProperty)
        throws SQLException {
    T bean = this.newInstance(type);

    for (int i = 1; i < columnToProperty.length; i++) {
        if (columnToProperty[i] == PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND) {
            continue;
        }
        PropertyDescriptor prop = props[columnToProperty[i]];
        Class<?> propType = prop.getPropertyType();

        Object value = null;
        if(propType != null) {
            value = this.processColumn(rs, i, propType);

            if (value == null && propType.isPrimitive()) {
                value = primitiveDefaults.get(propType);
            }
        }
        this.callSetter(bean, prop, value);
    }
    return bean;
}
```

As you can see the returned `bean` object has `T` type not `<T> T`. Why?

Comment: `<T>` is not part of the return type; T is the return type

Comment: It's a generic method. See [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Comment: You should check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377248/return-type-of-java-generic-methods), that I flagged as duplicate

Comment: I've found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888551/how-to-interpret-public-t-t-readobjectdata-classt-type-in-java