# java generic method signature

Tags: java, generics

I'm a bit confused about the syntax of generic methods.
My understanding after reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377248/return-type-of-java-generic-methods) was that generic method should be declared like this:

```java
public static <E> void printArray( E[] inputArray )
```

with `<E>` being a placeholder that informs that E is a generic type

So why do I find in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) things like this:

```
Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)
```

No placeholder?  I would have expect

```
<T> Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)
```

And why

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

This time there is a placeholder, but only for R and not for T. Why?

Comment: Most likely, the method is in a class that has a type parameter `T`, like `interface Stream<T>`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html, so the method doesn't accept a new type parameter, you're using one from the outer scope

Answer (score 5):

These methods are instance methods defined on the interface `Stream`, which defines the type parameter on the *type*:

```
public interface Stream<T> {
  Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T>)
}
```

...so the type parameter is defined on the interface, not the method.

As you noticed, type parameters that *aren't* defined on the interface are defined on a method-by-method basis, in the case of `map`.